# SQL Server: how to omit 'CreatedOn' column while creating a temp table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query (similar to the one below) that supposed to create a temporary table from a join:

```
SELECT p.pid,* 
INTO #temp_insert_inventory
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM main_inventory.dbo.Inv i
     LEFT JOIN web_inventory.dbo.Variant v ON i.id = v.ext4
     WHERE v.ext4 IS NULL
       AND i.qty > 0) PL
INNER JOIN web_inventory.dbo.Product p ON PL.invcode = p.ext
```

The problem is that SQL Server is refusing to create the temporary table because there are multiple `CreatedOn` columns being returned from the select.

I really don't need any one of these columns so how can I just omit it in the select?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

List out all the columns instead of `SELECT *`.

If you need both versions of the conflicting `CreatedOn` columns, you can use an **alias** for one of them. If you don't want the additional column at all then don't include it in the `SELECT` list.

---

> [Bad Habits to Kick: Using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: As far as I know it will not omit the column.

Comment: But you can use an alias to rename the column and avoid the naming conflict.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to rename a column that I don't need. Are you saying that I cannot just omit it instead?

Comment: @YanKleber: of course - if you **explicitly list out the columns you want** in your `SELECT` clause  - you can just leave out the `CreatedOn` columns from every single table ....

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way of explicitly list out the columns I do NOT want. ;)

Comment: There is not a way to do that. The only options are `SELECT *` (everything), `SELECT table.*` (everything in a table (or view) ), or `SELECT columnA, columnB...`

Comment: Thank you -- this is an objective answer. If I knew that is was not possible I wouldn't insist. Nonetheless it's a shame that MSSQL doesn't have this feature... I think that I am not the only one with such need and I am sure that with so many cool features it should be something kind of easy to be implemented in the engine.